# Split by double newline, prioritizing crlf

Tags: python, regex, split, newline, backtracking

The naive way to accomplish this would be:

```
import re
re.split(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2}', '...')
```

But:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2}', '\r\n\r\n\r\n')
['', '', '']
```

I'd like to get `['', '\r\n']` in this case. I probably need some sort of possessiveness or make it not backtrack. Is there a way?

Comment: I think you tried `re.split(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2}', '\r\n\r\n\r\n')` to get `['', '', '']`

Comment: Try  `r'(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n){2}'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Indeed, I used non-capturing parentheses. Didn't think  it would make a difference. And yes, your regular expression works. Care to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may restrict the `\n` and `\r` matching positions  using lookarounds to avoid matching them when in a CRLF:

```
r'(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n){2}'
```

Python test:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n){2}', '\r\n\r\n\r\n')
['', '\r\n']
```

See the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n){2}` - a non-capturing group (if you a capturing one, the value captured with the last iteration will be output into the resulting list with `re.split`, too) that matches two repetitions of:

  - `\r\n` - a CRLF sequence
  - `|` - or
  - `\r(?!\n)` - CR symbol not followed with LF
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<!\r)\n` - LF symbol not preceded with CR.